# Sessions with cURL

Tags: php, curl, get, request

I think I have a very simple problem. I'm currently working on an API and before you can use it, you have to login. Logging in goes via a http request, so to login you would access

```
http://myapi.com/login.php?email=mail@mail.com&password
```

for example.

When the email and the password are correct, I set some session variables and I start a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['idUser'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
print(json_encode(array("authenticated" => true)));
```

However, when I access the api and I do a request (not login) by cURL from my terminal, it says that I'm not authorized, while I first executed the login request. On every api call on another page I check the session variables. If they are set, the user is logged in:

```
function checkSession()
{
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['idUser']) || !isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
            print json_encode(array("error" => "Not authorized"));
            exit();
    }
}
```

Why does it say that I'm not authorized? When I access the pages from a web browser, everything is working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably because your PHP session uses cookies on your behalf to store the session on the user's browser. That's how your php app can recognize your users each time they make an HTTP request to your PHP pages.

You have to play with the 'cookie' options of cUrl.

Basically, you would first login  and store the session cookie with with

```
curl -c cookies.txt http://myapi.com/login.php?email=mail@mail.com&password=yourpassword
```

Then you do next requests telling cUrl to **send back** the cookie

```
curl -b cookies.txt http://myapi.com/login.php?email=mail@mail.com&password
```

You'll see your cookie(s) stored as plain text inside cookies.txt

Answer (score 2):

Need a cookie jar...

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/cookiejar.html

Browser cookies != your codes (curl client) cookies.

Now I got cookie monsters song stuck in my head...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was looking for the answer from @mbarthelemy but I will look into the cookie jar ;)