# Php : sending cookie in curl Request

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have below curl code to GET.

```
<?php  
function get_content($URL){
          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          return $data;
      }
 echo get_content("http://www.domain.com/cool.php");
?>
```

I have used http headers and cookie looks like below

```
xidseq:22
xid:b05f251c-8a72-4c2b-a230-e03b9c5c87b7&&BAYIDSAMFE1C013&343
data:dsfsfssdss
```

I need to send GET request to `http://www.domain.com/cool.php` with some cookies.

how do i put the cookie in cookie.txt ?? is there any specific format for cookies..or just posting it works ?

Comment: the cookie file should look like the old netscape-style cookies.txt

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752555/sessions-with-curl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020404/keeping-session-alive-with-curl-and-php <- has code example, gimme an up vote on one of those :)

Comment: its  irrelevant to my question

Comment: I was wrong with my previous comment -- you will most likely want both.  [Here is the best documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) I could find at the time.

Comment: I understand now.  Thing Marc B. was on right track then.  See RFC2965

Comment: Also, [this mailing list thread](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2005-03/0099.html) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885538/php-curl-and-cookies

Answer (score 1):

If script above doesn't work try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt'); /* make sure you provide FULL PATH to cookie files*/
```

Check file permissions and ownership on `dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt'` . Make sure file is writable.

To put the cookie in cookie.txt you need to visit certain web page that contains them - **only server side cookies you can fetch with cURL**, javascript cookies is not reachable vie cURL, at least not directly.

If you want to create cookies manually for your GET request, read about Netscape cookies format or - best way, save some 'real website' cookies via CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR to see and understand format.